# Insert a variable in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Weel, i'm creating a cicle with javascript and php.

This is my php

```
while  (($num_images > 0) && ($num_images < 5))
        {
             echo '<a href="javascript: submitform' . $num_images . '()"><img id="myImgId" class="nomarge" alt="" src="image' . $num_images . '.jpeg" width="' . $ver  . '" height="' . $hor . '"/></a>';
             echo $num_images;
             $num_images--;
        }
```

And now, I want my javascript to be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var img = 4;
for (img = 4, img > 0, img--) {
    function submitform() {document.myform.submit();}
}
</script>
```

Well... How do I make submitform1() myform1 ....

Comment: Don't declare multiple identical functions with different names! Make one function into which you pass a variable.

Comment: Please be more explicit. What's your aim ?

Comment: Poorly defined question.

Comment: sorry for not being more clear, my problem was simple, but sometimes the only think it takes is to try to explain the code to others. I can do what I was doing, without adding new cycle functions, just have to start the while AFTER the <a href="javascript: submitform()">

Anyway thank you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making new functions to submit each form, you could make a single function, `submitform()`, then pass the form index to it as a parameter (e.g. `i` as parameter).

Like this, You need to write only one function and that function, `submitform(i)` would submit the corresponding form.

You could make it as follows:

```
   function submitform(i){ 
       document.forms[i].submit()
    }
```

and PHP:

```
   echo '<a href="javascript: submitform(' . $num_images . ')"><img id="myImgId" class="nomarge" alt="" src="image' . $num_images . '.jpeg" width="' . $ver  . '" height="' . $hor . '"/></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var img = 4;
for (img = 4, img > 0, img--) {
    document['myform' + img].submit();
}
</script>
```

Caution, your first index will be 4 in this case. You want surely begin at the index 0.